# People are nested in groups, which in turn are nested in?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a summary term for a collective of groups. Specifically, I would like to make a general statement that **people are nested in groups, which in turn are nested in (?).**

Some examples to illustrate:

- Students are nested within classes (groups), which in turn are nested within a school (?).
- Students are nested in sorority chapters (groups), which in turn are nested within a sorority (?).
- Employees are nested in departments (groups), which in turn are nested within an organization (?).

I can summarize classes, departments, and sorority chapters with the summary term "group".

I have tried summarizing schools, sororities, and organizations with the summary terms "collective" and "society", yet I am not satisfied with either.

- "Collective" appears to imply a common goal. While departments in an organization likely pursue a common goal (e.g., improve company performance), I feel the term "collective" draws away attention from the fact that departments may also have competing interests. I am thus looking for a more neutral term than "collective".
- "Society" seems unsuitable because its meaning is already [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society): "A society is a group of people involved in persistent social interaction, or a large social grouping sharing the same geographical or social territory, typically subject to the same political authority and dominant cultural expectations." All people I talked to therefore found it confusing to refer to an organization as society.

**Edit 1.** I am hoping to find a term that is *intuitive and descriptive*. For example, I find that collective has an intuitive meaning (collection of items/people). While I like super-group, I feel the term does not convey the same intuitively graspable description for people who never encountered this term in mathematics.

**Edit 2.** Subgroup appears more intuitively graspable. However, I would like to start at the group level and find an overarching term from there (rather than going from group to subgroup).

Comment: How far do you want to go? Every group that falls under a bigger group is a sub-group, every group that contain another group is a super-group. That way you are set for infinity :)

Comment: @oerkelens, I like this solution! However, it made me realize I had not formulated my question with sufficient detail. Please see my edits.

Comment: Bigger groups ...

Comment: ["You're very clever, young man, very clever," said the old lady. "But it's turtles all the way down!"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps: People are nested in Groups, which in turn are nested in Communities.

Such that:

Students are nested within classes (groups), which in turn are nested within a school community.

Students are nested in sorority chapters (groups), which in turn are nested within a sorority community.

Employees are nested in departments (groups), which in turn are nested within an organizational community.

Comment: +1, this seems to me an elegant solution for many settings! I feel it does not quite apply to departments in an organization, though.

Comment: Perhaps departments in an organizational community.

Comment: I expanded a little for clarity &  to reflect your examples more directly.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate your effort, but I was looking for a single word.

Comment: Hmm. Community is the one word. Perhaps I did not clearly understand your examples, after all.

Comment: Possibly I've not clearly understood your question.

Answer (score -3):

You can refer to "classes" and the like as subgroups of "schools" and the like (groups).